# Unable to port-forward in private GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a private cluster in GKE which I access through Bastion host. Everything works except port-forwarding workloads (services). I suspect the issue is the private cluster and something to do with networking. The cloud console does not have the option to port forward as well. What may have caused this issue? Any idea would be great. Thanks

[image: Network Configuration of the Cluster]

**No port-forwarding option is visible**
[image: No Portword Option]

**EDIT**:
My goal is to get the port-forwarding commands easily accessible through the cloud console like in the picture below.

We have another cluster that was configured earlier. In it, I can see the debug / port-forwarding option side-by-side with the Ports.
[image: With Visible port-forwdin option]

Comment: When you say: "Everything works except..." what isn't working? Are you talking about ingress from public networks to a service inside your private cluster? Can you provide an example of what your goal is/what you're trying to achieve by editing your question? Thanks

Comment: @JKGunnink sorry for the confusion. I added more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have created a private cluster in my cloud console and deployed a service but the port forward option is enabled for me.**

**Below is my cluster configuration**:
[image]

**Below are the service details**:

[image]

**Can you try changing the target port as 80 and try again**

- You can port-forward the web preview while using the GCP shell to do port forwarding.
- When attempting port-forwarding from the shell, run command   `kubectl port-forward` and use the web preview option.
- You will see the output on the port you are forwarding and be redirected to a web preview.
- For further information see GCP official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview) and [blog](https://refine.dev/blog/kubectl-port-forward/#importance-of-accessing-internal-kubernetes-services) by Refine.

Comment: cannot see any cluster configuration or service details

Comment: @sithira Let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries. If the answer was helpful, What should I do [when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I had a misconfiguration in my service. Your answer helped. Thanks for the support 